# Tree data structure addnode

Tags: java, tree

I am having issue in understanding the following code. It is a tree data structure and I don't understand why do we need two node (parent and `focusnode`) in the `addnode()` method. I tried to do it with just `focusnode`but it doesn't work out. My idea is set `focusnode` to root, and keep looping it until `focusnode` is equal to `null`, and set `focusnode` to `newnode`.

```
public class tree {
  node root;
public class node{

    private int key;
    private node left;
    private node right;

    node(int key){
        this.key = key;     
}

    public int getkey(){
        return key;
    }

    public node getleft(){
        return left;
    }

    public node getright(){
        return right;
    }

}

public void addnode(int key){
    node newnode = new node(key);
    if(root == null){
        root = newnode;
    }else{
        node focusnode = root;
        node parent;

        while(true){

            parent = focusnode;
            if(key < focusnode.key){
                focusnode = focusnode.left;

                if(focusnode == null){
                    parent.left = newnode;
                    return;
                }
            }else{
                focusnode = focusnode.right;

                if(focusnode == null){
                    parent.right = newnode;
                    return;
                }


        }
        }
    }
}
public void runnode(node focusnode){
    if(focusnode != null){
        runnode(focusnode.left);        

    runnode(focusnode.right);
    System.out.println(focusnode.key);
    }

}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Because if you need to assign a new node as `parent`'s `.left` or `.right` child (which happens after you find that `focusnode == null`... meaning `.left`/`.right` is null), then you need a reference to that `.left/.right child (the reference is from the parent). You can't set focusnode to your newnode, because it will only assign your newnode to focusnode and not to`parent.right`or`parent.left`.

So you'll set the `focusnode` reference to your `newnode`, but the parent's `.left`/`.right` child nodes will not reference your `newnode`.

If you're coming from C/C++ or similar, imagine that all of these variables are pointers. `*focusnode` is pointing towards the same object that `*parent.left` is pointing to. Making `*focusnode` point to a different object will not change what `*parent.left` is pointing to.

All variables in Java are references (aside from primitives like int/double etc), which are similar to pointers in C/C++.

Comment: Can't we just get rid of parent, and use focusnode as reference?

Comment: `focusnode` is pointing to the `.left`/`.right` node. If you assign your `newnode` to `focusnode`, then `focusnode` will no longer reference `.left`/`.right` (which is currently `null`) but instead reference your `newnode`. But if we remember the `parent`, then we can say `parent.left` and change the reference of the parent's `.left`/`.right`, which is what the tree structure depends on. Assigning to `focusnode` does not change what `parent.left` is referencing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing the check like this:

```
if(key < focusnode.key){
    focusnode = focusnode.left;
        if(focusnode == null){
            focusnode = newnode;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

You are looping until focusnode is null, then creating a new node, but not attaching it to the the parent node. As a result, when you try to loop again, you can't loop past the root node since it has no children! If you wish to avoid dealing with the parent node variable, you need to check the child in the condition before setting focusnode, and only set focusnode if the child is not null. e.g:

```
if(key < focusnode.key){
        if(focusnode.left == null){
            focusnode.left = newnode;
            return;
        } else {
            foucusnode = focusnode.left;
        }
    }
}
```

The check is the same for the right side.